How to Get userId for Creating a Post in NextJS 15 with Prisma and Supabase?
NextJS 15, Supabase(DB), and Prisma are being used, and I am working on creating an endpoint API using Route Handlers. The issue I encountered is regarding the .createPost part where the data is:
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    const {userId, title, content}: createPostDto = await request.json();
    const createPost = await prisma.post.create({
      data: {
        title,
        content,
        userId,
      },
    });

    return NextResponse.json(createPost, { status: 201 });

data: { title, content, userId, }, // where to get userId? 

ERROR I GOT: Object literal may only specify known properties,
and 'userId' does not exist in type '(Without<PostCreateInput,
PostUncheckedCreateInput> & PostUncheckedCreateInput) | (Without<...>
& PostCreateInput)'.ts(2353)

I don't know where to get the userId value from. and below is my prisma schema:
model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  userName      String?
  email         String    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
  posts         Post[]

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
model Post {
  id        String   @id @default(uuid())
  userId    String
  title     String
  content   String
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  User      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id]) 
}

As an aside, if there are any other good methods for creating endpoint APIs, please feel free to recommend them.
i tried below code but has no effect
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id: userId },
    });

